# How to match F96 T12 bulbs with a ballast

Tags: wiring

I have a 2 lamp 8 ft fixture. It is T12. The ballast is new but I  don't know if it will power the bulbs. I don't want to change to LED yet since the ballast is new. The ballast has 2 red,blue, and yellow wires on one end and black , white on the other. The tombstones are original to the fixture (1988). They are typical F96 (nub) type. The fixture is connected to a loop switch and another power outlet down the line. I can't get but 1 of the lamps(new) to light. I suspect the ballast is incorrect or I need another kind of bulb. [image]

Comment: Usually there are specs on a label on the ballast as well as a wiring diagram.  If you could post a pic of that label, that would enable to help you better.  Also please take the tour so you can best know how to participate here.   Thanks.

Comment: We'll need more information.  We'll need to know whether you have regular F96 (1/4" diameter metal nub) or HO/VHO T96 (funny little plastic socket thingie maybe 1/2" wide) - a photo of the tombstone will suffice..  We'll also need either the model number of the ballast, or a photo of the label on it.  You can [edit] your question to add that.

Comment: Sorry when I say T96 I mean F96.  We really need the details on the ballasts and bulbs.  Fluorescent has become a really excellent technology and I'm staying with it and have reballasted probably 100 fixtures. But the details matter. The right lamp+ballast combo is key. Once we figure out what you have, we can figure the best match-up.

Comment: Could be that this ballast just can't handle 2 F96 bulbs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the wrong ballast. The **240** in the product number indicates it only serves up to 2-40W lamps. You probably need a GE 2620S-MV-N. If you can find one.

There has been an attempt to phase out the use of Type T12 lamps which are old technology. You might want to rethink using the T12 F96 lamps for a newer Type T8 lamp or install LED lamps, both much more efficient.

The energy savings are substantial, at least 33%. So the payback on the original cost of material can be made with 1-2 years of use.

Just something to consider.

Good Luck